# Can't run expo error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND exp.host

Tags: react-native, expo

this error appear suddenly after updating expo-cli to version `3.2.3`

I can't manage to run the application, it displays error like this when I run `expo start` / `yarn start`

```
Trying to open the project in iOS simulator...
Opening exp://127.0.0.1:19000 in iOS simulator

Expo  Press ? to show a list of all available commands.
Fetching the user profile failed
getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND exp.host
```

even I open `expo.host` from the browser loading.. I tried using 2 internet providers, change dns, flush dns, etc. still not loaded.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by deleting all expo related files and folders in my project
*.expo* and *.expo-shared* specifically.
when you run expo start, expo will automatically regenerate those files.
Make sure you are connected to the same network as your phone and PC,
you can try signing in and starting the project from your recent development tab on expo client.

if this dosen't work try reomving some devDependencies that you're not really using, then delete the node modules and install afresh.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar issue. It got resolved, as I logged in to the expo in my project folder.

Using `expo w`, you can check if you are logged-in in expo. and use `expo login` command to login

[image]